# Практические примеры применения масок svg

Tags: css, html5, svg, mask

Прочитал эти статьи по теории масок, но не уверен, что понял всё правильно

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/mask
http://css.yoksel.ru/svg-masks/

Вот пример по маскам, пробую изменять параметры, хочется понять основные закономерности, чтобы в будущем уверенно применять svg маски.

```html
<style>
.container {
width:50%;
height:50%;
}
</style>
<div class="container">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        viewBox="0 0 600 800" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" style="border:1px solid red;" >  
 <defs>
  <mask id="msk1">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="red" />
 <g fill="white">
       <!-- Left eye --> 
    <circle cx="400" cy="350" r="90"  />
    <!-- Right eye -->
   <circle cx="200" cy="350" r="90"  />
    </g> 
 </mask>
 </defs> 

<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHYc7.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" mask="url(#msk1)" />
</svg>  
</div>
```

Comment: если это перевод вопроса с en.so, то нелишним будет вставить ссылку на оригинал

Comment: @Alex нет, это моя собственная статья, которую я написал сегодня :))))

Comment: понятно) вопрос и ответ опубликованы в одно время, поэтому возникла мысль, что это перевод

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Примеры использования маски

Немного теории плюс примеры и можно сформулировать простые правила, которые будут помогать в освоении и практическом применении масок.

Можно представить маску в виде 2D объекта, например лист любого материала, который расположен между нашими глазами и объектом наблюдения.  В листе будут вырезаться отверстия, форма которых задаются элементами `svg` между тегами `<mask>`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1. Если маска полностью непрозрачна `fill="black"` мы ничего не увидим.

```html
<style>
.container {
width:50%;
height:50%;
}
</style>
<div class="container">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        viewBox="0 0 600 800" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" style="border:1px solid red;" >  
 <defs>
  <mask id="msk1">
    <g fill="black">
       <!-- Left eye --> 
    <circle cx="400" cy="350" r="90"  />
    <!-- Right eye -->
   <circle cx="200" cy="350" r="90"  />
    </g> 
 </mask>
 </defs> 

<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHYc7.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" mask="url(#msk1)" />
</svg>  
</div>
```

2. Маска имеет форму двух окружностей, которые полностью прозрачны,- `fill="white`"
   Видим после применения маски, вырезанные  части объекта, как они есть на оригинальном изображении.

```html
<style>
.container {
width:50%;
height:50%;
}
</style>
<div class="container">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        viewBox="0 0 600 800" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" style="border:1px solid red;" >  
 <defs>
  <mask id="msk1">
   <g fill="white">
   <!-- Left eye --> 
 <circle cx="400" cy="350" r="90"  />
   <!-- Right eye -->
  <circle cx="200" cy="350" r="90"  />
 </g> 
   </mask>
 </defs> 

<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHYc7.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" mask="url(#msk1)" />
</svg>  
</div>
```

3. Цвет заполнения маски находится между чёрным и белым цветом, то есть прозрачность маски будет между `0` и `1`

На примере часть маски для левого глаза `fill="gray"` для правого `fill="red"`

```html
<style>
.container {
width:50%;
height:50%;
}
</style>
<div class="container">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        viewBox="0 0 600 800" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" style="border:1px solid red;" >  
 <defs>
  <mask id="msk1">
   <g >
   <!-- Left eye --> 
 <circle cx="400" cy="350" r="90" fill="gray"  />
   <!-- Right eye -->
  <circle cx="200" cy="350" r="90" fill="red" />
 </g> 
   </mask>
 </defs> 

<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHYc7.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" mask="url(#msk1)" />
</svg>  
</div>
```

### Обработка фона вне маски

Для этой цели в теги `<mask>` добавляется прямоугольник занимающий всё пространство маскируемого объекта

`<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" />`

Принцип тот же,- для фона вне маски, если `fill="white"` этот участок останется неизменным. В итоге фон как есть, а зона действия маски зависит от прозрачности, то есть от выбора цвета заливки. Для маски,- это глаза `fill="black"` становятся непрозрачными.

```html
<style>
.container {
width:50%;
height:50%;
}
</style>
<div class="container">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        viewBox="0 0 600 800" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" style="border:1px solid red;" >  
 <defs>
  <mask id="msk1">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" />
 <g fill="black">
       <!-- Left eye --> 
    <circle cx="400" cy="350" r="90"  />
    <!-- Right eye -->
   <circle cx="200" cy="350" r="90"  />
    </g> 
 </mask>
 </defs> 

<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHYc7.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" mask="url(#msk1)" />
</svg>  
</div>
```

Теперь фон непрозрачный `fill="black"` маска `fill="white"`

В этой комбинации маска работает, как `clipPath`

```html
<style>
.container {
width:50%;
height:50%;
}
</style>
<div class="container">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        viewBox="0 0 600 800" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" style="border:1px solid red;" >  
 <defs>
  <mask id="msk1">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black" />
 <g fill="white">
       <!-- Left eye --> 
    <circle cx="400" cy="350" r="90"  />
    <!-- Right eye -->
   <circle cx="200" cy="350" r="90"  />
    </g> 
 </mask>
 </defs> 

<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHYc7.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" mask="url(#msk1)" />
</svg>  
</div>
```

Фон полупрозрачный `fill="red"` маска прозрачна `fill="white"`

```html
<style>
.container {
width:50%;
height:50%;
}
</style>
<div class="container">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        viewBox="0 0 600 800" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" >  
 <defs>
  <mask id="msk1">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="red" />
 <g fill="white">
       <!-- Left eye --> 
    <circle cx="400" cy="350" r="90"  />
    <!-- Right eye -->
   <circle cx="200" cy="350" r="90"  />
    </g> 
 </mask>
 </defs> 

<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHYc7.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" mask="url(#msk1)" />
</svg>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

### Примеры с подключением прозрачности `stroke`

У базовых элементов SVG: `line`; `polyline`, `polygon`, `rect`,`circle',`ellipse`,'path`

- есть атрибут - `stroke-width` задавая ширину и прозрачность которого, можно ещё
  расширить возможности маски.
- также представляет интерес использование `stroke-dasharray` и
  `stroke-dashoffset`

  **#1**
  `<circle cx="500" cy="300" r="250" fill="#5F5F5F" stroke-width="250" stroke="white"`

  *Окружность полупрозрачна, широкая строка прозрачна*

```html
<style>
.container {
width:50%;
height:50%;
}
</style>
<div class="container">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        viewBox="0 0 1000 667" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"  >  
 <defs>
  <mask id="msk1">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="red" stroke-width="1" stroke="white" />
       
    <circle cx="500" cy="300" r="250" fill="#5F5F5F" stroke-width="250" stroke="white"  />
 </mask>
 </defs> 
<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWG1v.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" mask="url(#msk1)" />
</svg>  
</div>
```

**#2**

Несколько окружностей
 Центр - окружность с самым малым радиусом сделан наиболее прозрачным по сравнению с внешними окружностями

`<circle cx="500" cy="300" r="100" fill="#5F5F5F" stroke-width="25" stroke="white" />`

```html
<style>
.container {
width:50%;
height:50%;
}
</style>
<div class="container">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        viewBox="0 0 1000 667" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"  >  
 <defs>
  <mask id="msk1">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="red"
      stroke-width="1" stroke="white" />
 
       
    <circle cx="500" cy="300" r="250" fill="#5F5F5F"
       stroke- width="25" stroke="white" />
    <circle cx="500" cy="300" r="200" fill="#5F5F5F"
       stroke-width="25" stroke="white" />
     <circle cx="500" cy="300" r="150" fill="#5F5F5F" 
       stroke-width="25" stroke="white" />
     <circle cx="500" cy="300" r="100" fill="#C7C7C7"
      stroke-width="25" stroke="white" />   
     
 </mask>
 </defs> 

<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWG1v.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" mask="url(#msk1)" />
</svg>  
</div>
```

**#3**

```html
<style>
.container {
width:50%;
height:50%;
}
</style>
<div class="container">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        viewBox="0 0 2110 1410" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"  >  
 <defs>
  <mask id="msk1">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="red" stroke-width="1"  />
  <circle cx="1250" cy="1000" r="290" fill="#979797" stroke-width="70" stroke="white"  />
 </mask>
</defs> 

<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/npNcn.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" mask="url(#msk1)" />
</svg>  
</div>
```

**#4**

*Использование `stroke-dasharray`*

Делим окружность на 6 равных сегментов, у которых длина черты - `250px`, пробел - `64px`

`<circle cx="1200" cy="850" r="300" fill="red" stroke-width="200" stroke="white" stroke-dasharray="250 64" />`

```html
  

<style>
.container {
width:50%;
height:50%;
}
</style>
<div class="container">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        viewBox="0 0 2110 1410" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"  >  
 <defs>
  <mask id="msk1">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="red" stroke-width="1" stroke="white" />
  <circle cx="1200" cy="850" r="300" fill="red" stroke-width="200" stroke="white" stroke-dasharray="250 64" />
  
 </mask>
 </defs> 

<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/npNcn.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" mask="url(#msk1)" />
</svg>  
</div>
```

**#5**

Ещё пример с `stroke-dasharray` и очень широкой строкой - `stroke-width="400"`

```html
<style>
.container {
width:50%;
height:50%;
}
</style>
<div class="container">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        viewBox="0 0 1000 667" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"  >  
 <defs>
  <mask id="msk1">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="red" stroke-width="1" stroke="white" />
    <circle cx="500" cy="300" r="300" fill="#5F5F5F" stroke-width="400" stroke="white" stroke-dasharray="25 64" />
    
 </mask>
 </defs> 

<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWG1v.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" mask="url(#msk1)" />
</svg>  
</div>
```