# Заливка объекта снизу-вверх

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, анимация

Как на SVG создать круглый бордюр с заливкой от низа к верху.

Ниже, как это реализовано с помощью CSS:

```js
$('input[type="range"]').bind('change mousemove',function(){
  $('.border-bg').height($(this).val()+'%');
});
```

```css
.border {
  display: block;
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: rgba(255,0,0,.25);
  position: relative;
}

.border::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  height: calc(100% - 20px);
  margin: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.border-bg {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30%;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: auto;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="border">
  <div class="border-bg"></div>
</div>

<input type="range" min="0" value="30" max="100" step="1">
```

---

Доп. вопрос:
Как использовать не только бордюр, а допустим `слой-маску`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Изначально красный круг скрыт маской, роль которой выполняет прямоугольник, полностью перекрывая круг.
При движении маски вверх постепенно показывается освободившаяся часть круга, создавая иллюзию рисования.

```css
.container{
width:50%;
height:50%;
}

#crc1{
fill:none;
stroke:red;
stroke-width:10;
mask:url(#msk1);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg height="200" width="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
  <defs>
    <mask id="msk1" >
    <rect fill="white" width="100%" height="100%" />    
    <rect fill="red" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" >
      <animate attributeName="y" dur="4s" begin="0s" values="0;-200" fill="freeze" />
   </rect> 
  </mask> 
  </defs>
  <circle id="crc1"  cx="100" cy="100" r="90" />
</svg>

</div>
```

Применение масок очень мощный и гибкий инструмент, меняя всего один атрибут можно легко реализовать различные варианты рисования

**Рисование сверху вниз**
Вместо значения - `values="0;-200"` устанавливаем `values="0;200"`

```css
.container{
width:50%;
height:50%;
}

#crc1{
fill:none;
stroke:red;
stroke-width:10;
mask:url(#msk1);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg height="200" width="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
  <defs>
    <mask id="msk1" >
    <rect fill="white" width="100%" height="100%" />    
    <rect fill="red" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" >
      <animate attributeName="y" dur="4s" begin="0s" values="0;200" fill="freeze" />
   </rect> 
  </mask> 
  </defs>
  <circle id="crc1"  cx="100" cy="100" r="90" />
</svg>

</div>
```

**Слева- направо**

В этом случае будем анимировать координату "x" прямоугольника маски

```
<animate attributeName="x" dur="4s" begin="0s" values="0;200" fill="freeze" />
```

```css
.container{
width:50%;
height:50%;
}

#crc1{
fill:none;
stroke:red;
stroke-width:10;
mask:url(#msk1);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg height="200" width="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
  <defs>
    <mask id="msk1" >
    <rect fill="white" width="100%" height="100%" />    
    <rect fill="red" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" >
      <animate attributeName="x" dur="4s" begin="0s" values="0;200" fill="freeze" />
   </rect> 
  </mask> 
  </defs>
  <circle id="crc1"  cx="100" cy="100" r="90" />
</svg>

</div>
```

**Движение в левую сторону**

```css
.container{
width:50%;
height:50%;
}

#crc1{
fill:none;
stroke:red;
stroke-width:10;
mask:url(#msk1);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg height="200" width="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
  <defs>
    <mask id="msk1" >
    <rect fill="white" width="100%" height="100%" />    
    <rect fill="red" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" >
      <animate attributeName="x" dur="4s" begin="0s" values="0;-200" fill="freeze" />
   </rect> 
  </mask> 
  </defs>
  <circle id="crc1"  cx="100" cy="100" r="90" />
</svg>

</div>
```

Comment: Как всегда понятный и развёрнутый ответ. Спасибо! Ещё вопрос, как использовать какую-нибудь маску с таким же эффектом заполнения?

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 да не за что, не понял только вопрос, разве в моем ответе не использована маска? Если не трудно задай тогда дополнительный вопрос, чтобы я понял, что вы хотите получить на выходе. Можно в чате.

Comment: В теге <mask> можно использовать "что угодно"?

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 да, все основные фигуры svg  Почитай мою статью по маскам.  Пытался донести отдельные принципы максимально просто и доходчиво https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/919186/28748

Answer (score 3):

### Использование `stroke-dasharray`

Все привыкли к стандартному использованию рисования  из  начала или конца отрезка  в сторону увеличения или уменьшения линии.

Поэтому понять сразу, как можно использовать этот атрибут для одновременного рисования из одной точки в разные стороны, довольно сложно.   Начнём с самых простых основ.

Допустим у нас окружность `R="90px"` Длина окружности будет равна  `C=2πr = 2 * 3.14 * 90 ≈ 565.2`

Половина окружности равна `565,2 / 2 ≈ 282.6`

- `stroke-dasharray="282.6 282.6"`  первая цифра длина черты (полокружности), вторая цифра пробел

```css
.container{
width:100%;
height:100%;
}

#crc1{
fill:none;
stroke:red;
stroke-width:10;
}

#bg{
fill:none;
stroke:#D5D5D5;
stroke-width:10;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg height="200" width="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
  <defs>
    
  </defs>
   <circle id="bg"  cx="100" cy="100" r="90" />
  <circle id="crc1"   cx="100" cy="100" r="90"  stroke-dasharray="282.6 282.6"/>
  
  </svg>
</div>
```

Пока всё понятно - первая половина окружности закрашена, вторая пробел

- Теперь установим `stroke-dasharray="282.6 0"`

  Первая половина окружности закрашивается, вторая половина окружности пропускается, снова закрашивается половина окружности, это уже вторая половина и снова пропуск. В итоге закрашивается вся окружность.

```css
.container{
width:100%;
height:100%;
}

#crc1{
fill:none;
stroke:red;
stroke-width:10;
}

#bg{
fill:none;
stroke:#D5D5D5;
stroke-width:10;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg height="200" width="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
  <defs>
    
  </defs>
   <circle id="bg"  cx="100" cy="100" r="90" />
  <circle id="crc1"   cx="100" cy="100" r="90"  stroke-dasharray="282.6 0"/>
  
  </svg>
</div>
```

- Теперь установим `stroke-dasharray="0 282.6"`

  Первая половина окружности, где должна быть черта пропускается, вторая половина окружности, где должен быть пробел пропускается. В итоге вся окружность не окрашена.

  ```css
  .container{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  }

  #crc1{
  fill:none;
  stroke:red;
  stroke-width:10;
  }

  #bg{
  fill:none;
  stroke:#D5D5D5;
  stroke-width:10;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div class="container">
  <svg height="200" width="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
    <defs>
      
    </defs>
     <circle id="bg"  cx="100" cy="100" r="90" />
    <circle id="crc1"   cx="100" cy="100" r="90"  stroke-dasharray="0 282.6"/>
    
    </svg>
  </div>
  ```

Используя эти данные напишем формулу анимации при которой окружность будет заполняться из одной точки в разные стороны:

```
 <circle id="crc1" transform="rotate(90 100 100)"  cx="100" cy="100" r="90" stroke-dasharray="0 282.6 0 282.6"  >
     <animate attributeName="stroke-dasharray" values="0 282.6 0 282.6;0 0 565.2 0" dur="5s" fill="freeze" />
    </circle>
```

**Ниже полный код заполнения слева-направо**

```css
.container{
width:100%;
height:100%;
}

#crc1{
fill:none;
stroke:red;
stroke-width:10;
}

#bg{
fill:none;
stroke:#D5D5D5;
stroke-width:10;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg height="200" width="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
  <defs>
    
  </defs> 
  <circle id="bg"  cx="100" cy="100" r="90" />
   <circle id="crc1" transform="rotate(0 100 100)"  cx="100" cy="100" r="90" stroke-dasharray="0 282.6 0 282.6"  >
   <animate attributeName="stroke-dasharray" values="0 282.6 0 282.6;0 0 565.2 0" dur="5s" fill="freeze" />
   </circle>
</svg>

</div>
```

**Сверху-вниз**

```css
.container{
width:100%;
height:100%;
}

#crc1{
fill:none;
stroke:red;
stroke-width:10;
}

#bg{
fill:none;
stroke:#D5D5D5;
stroke-width:10;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg height="200" width="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
  <defs>
    
  </defs> 
  <circle id="bg"  cx="100" cy="100" r="90" />
   <circle id="crc1" transform="rotate(90 100 100)"  cx="100" cy="100" r="90" stroke-dasharray="0 282.6 0 282.6"  >
   <animate attributeName="stroke-dasharray" values="0 282.6 0 282.6;0 0 565.2 0" dur="5s" fill="freeze" />
   </circle>
</svg>

</div>
```

**Справа - налево**

```css
.container{
width:100%;
height:100%;
}

#crc1{
fill:none;
stroke:red;
stroke-width:10;
}

#bg{
fill:none;
stroke:#D5D5D5;
stroke-width:10;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg height="200" width="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
  <defs>
    
  </defs> 
  <circle id="bg"  cx="100" cy="100" r="90" />
   <circle id="crc1" transform="rotate(180 100 100)"  cx="100" cy="100" r="90" stroke-dasharray="0 282.6 0 282.6"  >
   <animate attributeName="stroke-dasharray" values="0 282.6 0 282.6;0 0 565.2 0" dur="5s" fill="freeze" />
   </circle>
</svg>

</div>
```

**Снизу - вверх**

```css
.container{
width:100%;
height:100%;
}

#crc1{
fill:none;
stroke:red;
stroke-width:10;
}

#bg{
fill:none;
stroke:#D5D5D5;
stroke-width:10;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg height="200" width="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
  <defs>
    
  </defs> 
  <circle id="bg"  cx="100" cy="100" r="90" />
   <circle id="crc1" transform="rotate(270 100 100)"  cx="100" cy="100" r="90" stroke-dasharray="0 282.6 0 282.6"  >
   <animate attributeName="stroke-dasharray" values="0 282.6 0 282.6;0 0 565.2 0" dur="5s" fill="freeze" />
   </circle>
</svg>

</div>
```

Comment: Ого, красивая реализация вышла.

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 великий и могучий svg, одна формула и уже можно делать всякие лоадеры, прогрессбары и т.д.