# Как сделать анимацию стрелки, прямоугольника svg

Tags: jquery, css, css3, svg, анимация

https://cpeople.ru/portfolio/ в портфолио есть иконка svg, при наведении на которую анимируется стрелка вместе с прямоугольником. Как такое реализовать?

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="40" height="40" viewBox="0 0 40 40" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
<defs>
<clipPath id="animationMask_KrN4OCyZwL">
<rect width="40" height="40" x="0" y="0"></rect>
</clipPath>
</defs>
<g clip-path="url(#animationMask_KrN4OCyZwL)" fill="#626363" 
stroke="#626363" stroke-width="1px">
<g fill="#626363" stroke="#626363" stroke-width="1px"></g>
<g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,-4,-4)" fill="#626363" opacity="1" style="user-select: none;" stroke="#626363" stroke-width="1px">
<g fill="#626363" opacity="1" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,24,24)" 
stroke="#626363" stroke-width="1px">
<path fill="#626363" fill-opacity="0" 
stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" 
stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke="#626363" 
stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="2px" 
d="M0 0 M19,0 C19,-10.493 10.493,-19 0,-19 C-10.493,-19 -19,-10.493 -19,0 C-19,10.493 -10.493,19 0,19 C10.493,19 19,10.493 19,0z">
</path></g></g>
<g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,8,5.999999999999999)" fill="#626363" opacity="1"
stroke="#626363" stroke-width="1px" style="user-select: none;">
<g fill="#626363" opacity="1" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,18,8)" 
stroke="#626363" stroke-width="1px">
<path fill="#626363" fill-opacity="0" 
stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" 
stroke="#626363" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="2px" 
d="M0 0 M-3,-3 C-3,-3 3,-3 3,-3 C3,-3 3,3 3,3">
</path></g>
<g fill-opacity="0" fill="#626363" opacity="1" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,16,10)"
stroke="#626363" stroke-width="1px">
<path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" 
stroke="#626363" stroke-width="2px"  stroke-opacity="1"
d="M0 0 M4,-4 C4,-4 -4,4 -4,4" fill="#626363">
</path></g></g>
<g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,8,6)" fill="#626363" opacity="1" 
stroke="#626363" stroke-width="1px" style="user-select: none;">
<g fill="#626363" opacity="1" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,12,14)" 
stroke="#626363" stroke-width="1px">
<path fill="#626363" fill-opacity="0" 
stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" 
stroke="#626363" stroke-width="2px" stroke-opacity="1" 
d="M0 0 M0,-7 C0,-7 -7,-7 -7,-7 C-7,-7 -7,7 -7,7 C-7,7 7,7 7,7 C7,7 7,0 7,0" >
</path></g></g>
<g fill="#626363" fill="#626363" 
stroke="#626363" stroke-width="1px" 
style="user-select: none; display: none;">
<g stroke="#626363" stroke-width="1px">
<path fill="#626363" fill-opacity="0" 
stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" 
stroke="#626363" stroke-width="1px"
style="display: none;">
</path></g></g>
<g fill="#626363" stroke="#626363" stroke-width="1px" 
style="user-select: none; display: none;">
<g fill="#626363" stroke="#626363" stroke-width="1px">
<path fill="#626363" fill-opacity="0" 
stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" 
stroke="#626363" stroke-width="1px" 
style="display: none;">
</path></g></g>
<g fill="#626363" style="user-select: none; display: none;" 
stroke="#626363" stroke-width="1px">
<g fill="#626363" stroke="#626363" stroke-width="1px">
<path fill="#626363" fill-opacity="0" 
stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" 
stroke="#626363" stroke-width="1px" style="display: none;">
</path></g>
<g fill="#626363" stroke="#626363" stroke-width="1px">
<path fill="#626363" fill-opacity="0" 
stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" 
stroke="#626363" stroke-width="1px" style="display: none;">
</path>
</g></g></g>
</svg>
```

Comment: делалось это в after-effects

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Доработал код иконки:

```css
.container {
width:30%;
height:30%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
 
  <g fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke="gray" >
   <circle id="crc1" cx="12" cy="12" r="11" />
  <path id="line1" d="m17 9-7 7" />
  <path id="arrow" d="m13 7h6v6" />
  <path id="rec1" d="m17 14v5H6v-9h5" />
  </g>
</svg>
</div>
```

- Для анимации используется атрибут патча `stroke-dasharray`

  Вычисление длин дало результаты:

`<path id="line1"  = 10px`

`<path id="arrow" = 12px`

`<path id="rec1" = 30px`

**Анимация в два этапа:**

1. Увеличение прозрачности, иконка становится ярче

`<animate AttributeName="stroke-opacity" dur="0.05s"   values="0.5;1" begin="svg1.mouseover" end="svg1.mouseout" fill="freeze" />`

2. Исчезновение и рисование контуров иконки

   `<path id="rec1" stroke-dasharray="30" stroke-dashoffset="0" d="m17 14v5H6v-9h5" >
        <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" dur="1s" begin="svg1.click" values="0;30;30;0" fill="freeze"/>
     </path>`

*Ниже полный код. Анимация начинается после наведения*

```css
.container {
width:15%;
height:15%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg id="svg1" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
 
  <g fill="none"  stroke="gray" stroke-opacity="0.5" >
   <circle id="crc1" cx="12" cy="12" r="11" />
  <path id="line1" stroke-dasharray="10 " stroke-dashoffset="0" d="m17 9-7 7" >
    <animate
      attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
      dur="1s"
      begin="svg1.mouseover"
      values="0;10;0"
      fill="freeze"
      restart="whenNotActive"/>
  </path> 
  <path id="arrow"
    stroke-dasharray="12"
    stroke-dashoffset="0"
    d="m13 7h6v6" >
      <animate
        attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
        dur="1s"
        begin="svg1.mouseover"
        values="0;12;0"
        fill="freeze"
        restart="whenNotActive"/>
  </path> 
  <path id="rec1" stroke-dasharray="30" stroke-dashoffset="0" d="m17 14v5H6v-9h5" >
     <animate
       attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
       dur="1s"
       begin="svg1.mouseover"
       values="0;30;0"
       fill="freeze"
       restart="whenNotActive"/>
  </path> 
    <animate
      attributeName="stroke-opacity"
      dur="0.05s"
      values="0.5;1"
      begin="svg1.mouseover"
      fill="freeze"
      restart="whenNotActive" />
  </g>
</svg>
</div>
```

*Второй вариант анимации, - сначала рисуется стрелка, затем прямоугольник.*

Задержка рисования прямоугольника реализуется командой - `begin="an_Line.end-0.5s"`

```css
.container {
width:15%;
height:15%;

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg id="svg1" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
 
  <g fill="none"  stroke="gray" stroke-opacity="0.5" >
   <circle id="crc1" cx="12" cy="12" r="11" />
  <path id="line1" stroke-dasharray="10 " stroke-dashoffset="0" d="m17 9-7 7" >
    <animate id="an_Line"
     attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
     dur="1s"
     begin="svg1.mouseover"
     values="0;10;0"
     fill="freeze"
     restart="whenNotActive"/>
  </path> 
  <path id="arrow" stroke-dasharray="12" stroke-dashoffset="0" d="m13 7h6v6" >
    <animate
      attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
      dur="1s"
      begin="svg1.mouseover"
      values="0;12;0"
      fill="freeze"
      restart="whenNotActive"/>
  </path> 
  <path id="rec1" stroke-dasharray="30" stroke-dashoffset="0" d="m17 14v5H6v-9h5" >
     <animate
       attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
       dur="1s"
       begin="an_Line.end-0.1s"
       values="0;30;0"
       fill="freeze"
       restart="whenNotActive"/>
  </path> 
    <animate
      attributeName="stroke-opacity"
      dur="0.05s"
      values="0.5;1"
      begin="svg1.mouseover"
      end="svg1.mouseout"
      fill="freeze"
      restart="whenNotActive" />
  </g>
</svg>
</div>
```

**Вариант с картинкой:**

```css
.img1 {
position:relative;
}
.container {
position:absolute;
width:5%;
height:5%;
top:12%;
left:2%;

}
```

```html
<div class="img1"> 
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2R4j.png" > 
</div>
 
<div class="container">
<svg id="svg1" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 24 24"> 

  
 
  <g fill="none"  stroke="gold" stroke-opacity="0.5" >
   <circle id="crc1" cx="12" cy="12" r="11" />
  <path id="line1" stroke-dasharray="10 " stroke-dashoffset="0" d="m17 9-7 7" >
    <animate
      id="an_Line"
      attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
      dur="1s"
      begin="svg1.mouseover"
      values="0;10;0"
      fill="freeze"
      restart="whenNotActive"/>
  </path> 
  <path id="arrow" stroke-dasharray="12" stroke-dashoffset="0" d="m13 7h6v6" >
    <animate
    attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
    dur="1s"
    begin="svg1.mouseover"
    values="0;12;0"
    fill="freeze"
    restart="whenNotActive"/>
  </path> 
  <path id="rec1" stroke-dasharray="30" stroke-dashoffset="0" d="m17 14v5H6v-9h5" >
     <animate
       attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
       dur="1s"
       begin="svg1.mouseover"
       values="0;30;0"
       fill="freeze"
       restart="whenNotActive"/>
  </path> 
    <animate
      attributeName="stroke-opacity"
      dur="0.05s"
      values="0.5;1"
      begin="svg1.mouseover"
      fill="freeze"
      restart="whenNotActive" />
  </g>
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Отлично. Но мне кажется, что синхронно было бы прикольнее... В том смысле, если бы прямоугольник и стрелка появлялись и исчезали одновременно

Comment: @Air так первый вариант именно так и сделан

Comment: У тя столько примеров, что я этот пример пропустил...))))))

Comment: спасибо большое , а можно что при наведении анимация работала?

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: @Alexandr_TT там же другая анимация ...из центра она ..не совсем то ...

Comment: @ПавелВаршавский изменил направление, но в принципе это не принципиально :)

Comment: @Alexandr_TT там из центра должно быть - примерно как будто круг скалируется и потом опять становится нулевым ...в афтер эффектс это делается за пол секунды ..но я подумал лучше уж так ...посмотрите у мен в примере ..только надо на svg без этого липового круга ..

Comment: @ПавелВаршавский  я посмотрел у тебя в примере, не будь перфекционистом, нормально всё, почему нужно повторять, до ms, как там где-то тётя или дядя сделали. Не вызывают они у меня доверия, глядя на ихний код иконки :)) Главное показана техника, как это в принципе делается

Comment: @Alexandr_TT  так этот кож весь не их ..я же говорю это bodymovin - если ты видел [это всё сделано в этом плагине для AE](https://codepen.io/search/pens?q=bodymovin%20&page=1&order=popularity&depth=everything&show_forks=on)

Comment: @ПавелВаршавский спасибо за инфу, интересно, не работал с этим плагином

Comment: @Элвин, слева вверху у ответа есть серая галочка, на которую нужно нажать, чтобы принять ответ. Так вы выразите благодарность ответившему и сами также получите 2 балла за это действие.

Answer (score 2):

Это конечно больше хак чем верное решение но примерно так

Хотя в примере использован bodymovin.js что говорит о том что рисовали в AI и для анимации использовали After Effects с его плагином bodymovin

Но я совместил SVG с анимацией css3

```css
a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 48px;
  position: relative;
}

a:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

a:hover:after {
  animation: scalable 0.64s linear;
}

@keyframes scalable {
  0%,
  100% {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
  }
  50% {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="">
  <svg version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 164 150" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <g transform="translate(-17 -41)">
  <ellipse cx="98" cy="116" rx="79" ry="72" style="fill-rule:evenodd;fill:#ffffff;paint-order:markers stroke fill;stroke-dashoffset:144;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-opacity:.45;stroke-width:6;stroke:#000000"/>
  <rect x="54" y="92" width="73" height="63" style="fill:none;opacity:.45;paint-order:markers stroke fill;stroke-dashoffset:38;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-width:2.3;stroke:#000000"/>
  <rect x="101" y="92" width="26" height="18" style="fill:none;paint-order:markers stroke fill;stroke-dashoffset:144;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-width:4;stroke:#ffffff"/>
  <g transform="matrix(.3 .33 -.33 .3 134 52)" style="fill:none;stroke-width:5.6">
   <path d="m117 74-60-52-51 52" style="fill:none;stroke-opacity:.45;stroke-width:5.6;stroke:#000000"/>
   <path d="m59 42 .44 148" style="fill:none;stroke-opacity:.45;stroke-width:5.6;stroke:#000000"/>
  </g>
 </g>
</svg>

</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Вариант с использованием масок SVG

Чтобы анимация появления стрелки и рисования контейнера начиналась и заканчивалась в центре круга, можно использовать две половинки маски, которые будут двигаться в разные стороны от центра.

Роль двух половинок маски будут играть два прямоугольника

```css
.container {
width:30%;
height:30%;

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg  id="svg1" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
 
 <defs>
 <mask id="msk1">
    <rect  fill="white" width="100%" height="100%" />   
     <rect id="half_top" fill="#242424"   x="0" y="-12"  width="24" height="12" >  
           <animate attributeName="y"
       dur="2s"
    begin="svg1.mouseover"
    values="-12;0;-12"
    fill="freeze"
    repeatCount="1"
    restart="whenNotActive" /> 
   </rect>  
       <rect id="half_down" fill="#242424"   x="0" y="24"  width="24" height="12" >  
     
    <animate attributeName="y"
      dur="2s"
   begin="svg1.mouseover"
   values="24;10;24"
   fill="freeze"
   repeatCount="1"
   restart="whenNotActive" /> 
   </rect>  
  </mask> 
  </defs>
  
   <circle id="crc1" cx="12" cy="12" r="11" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke="gray" />
  <g mask="url(#msk1)" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke="gray" >
  <path id="line1" d="M10 16 17 9V9M13 7" />
  <path id="arrow" d="m13 7h6v6" />
  <path id="rec1" d="m17 14v5H6v-9h5" /> 
  
  </g>
</svg>
</div>
```

- Поворачиваем прямоугольники на 60 градусов
  `transform="rotate(60 12 12)"`

```css
.container {
width:30%;
height:30%;

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg  id="svg1" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
 
 <defs>
 <mask id="msk1">
    <rect  fill="white" width="100%" height="100%" />   
     <rect id="half_top"  transform="rotate(60 12 12)" fill="#242424"   x="0" y="-12"  width="24" height="12" >  
           <animate attributeName="y"
       dur="2s"
    begin="svg1.mouseover"
    values="-12;0;-12"
    fill="freeze"
    repeatCount="1"
    restart="whenNotActive" /> 
   </rect>  
       <rect id="half_down"  transform="rotate(60 12 12)" fill="#242424"   x="0" y="24"  width="24" height="12" >  
     
    <animate attributeName="y"
      dur="2s"
   begin="svg1.mouseover"
   values="24;10;24"
   fill="freeze"
   repeatCount="1"
   restart="whenNotActive" /> 
   </rect>  
  </mask> 
  </defs>
  
   <circle id="crc1" cx="12" cy="12" r="11" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke="gray" />
  <g mask="url(#msk1)" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke="gray" >
  <path id="line1" d="M10 16 17 9V9M13 7" />
  <path id="arrow" d="m13 7h6v6" />
  <path id="rec1" d="m17 14v5H6v-9h5" /> 
  
  </g>
</svg>
</div>
```

*Выглядит получше, но всё равно не реалистично*

Выводим маскирование контейнера прямоугольника `<path id="rec1" d="m17 14v5H6v-9h5"` из под действия маски, остаётся только стрелка, а контейнеру присваиваем анимацию с помощью атрибута `stroke-dashoffset`

```
<path id="rec1" d="m17 14v5H6v-9h5" stroke-dashoffset="0" stroke-dasharray="30" fill="none" stroke="gray" stroke-linecap="butt" >
     <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" dur="1.65s" begin="svg1.mouseover" values="0;30;0" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive"/>
   </path>
```

```css
.container {
width:30%;
height:30%;

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg  id="svg1" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
 
 <defs>
 <mask id="msk1">
    <rect  fill="white" width="100%" height="100%" />   
     <rect id="r_top" fill="#0C0C0C" transform="rotate(60 12 12)"   x="0" y="-12"  width="24" height="12" >  
      
     <animate attributeName="y" dur="2s" begin="svg1.mouseover"  values="-12;0;-12" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1" restart="whenNotActive" /> 
   </rect>  
       <rect id="t_down" fill="#0C0C0C" transform="rotate(60 12 12)"  x="0" y="24"  width="24" height="12" >  
     
    <animate attributeName="y" dur="2s" begin="svg1.mouseover" values="24;10;24" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1" restart="whenNotActive" /> 
   </rect>  
  </mask> 
  </defs>
  
   <circle id="crc1" cx="12" cy="12" r="11" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke="gray" />
<g mask="url(#msk1)" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke="gray" >
  <path id="line1" d="M10 16 17 9V9M13 7" />
  <path id="arrow" d="m13 7h6v6" />
</g> 
 <path id="rec1" d="m17 14v5H6v-9h5" stroke-dashoffset="0" stroke-dasharray="30" fill="none" stroke="gray" stroke-linecap="butt" >
     <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" dur="1.65s" begin="svg1.mouseover" values="0;30;0" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive"/>
   </path>  
  
  
</svg>
</div>
```

Делаем маску непрозрачной `fill="black"` подробнее о масках [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/919186/28748)

```css
.container {
width:10%;
height:10%;

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg  id="svg1" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
 
 <defs>
 <mask id="msk1">
    <rect  fill="white" width="100%" height="100%" />   
     <rect id="r_top" fill="black" transform="rotate(60 12 12)"   x="0" y="-12"  width="24" height="12" >  
      
     <animate attributeName="y" dur="1s" begin="svg1.mouseover"  values="-12;0;-12" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1" restart="whenNotActive" /> 
   </rect>  
       <rect id="t_down" fill="black" transform="rotate(60 12 12)"  x="0" y="24"  width="24" height="12" >  
     
    <animate attributeName="y" dur="1s" begin="svg1.mouseover" values="24;10;24" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1" restart="whenNotActive" /> 
   </rect>  
  </mask> 
  </defs>
   
   <circle id="crc1" cx="12" cy="12" r="11" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke="gray" />
<g mask="url(#msk1)" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke="gray" >
  <path id="line1" d="M10 16 17 9V9M13 7" />
  <path id="arrow" d="m13 7h6v6" />
</g> 
 <path id="rec1" d="m17 14v5H6v-9h5" stroke-dashoffset="0" stroke-dasharray="30" fill="none" stroke="gray" stroke-linecap="butt" >
     <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" dur="0.8s" begin="svg1.mouseover" values="0;30;0" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive"/>
   </path>  
  
  
</svg>
</div>
```

**Финальная часть + картинка**

```css
.img1 {
position:relative;
}
.container {
position:absolute;
width:5%;
height:5%;
top:2%;
left:2%;

}
```

```html
<div class="img1"> 
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZE0fb.jpg" > 
</div>
 
<div class="container">
<svg  id="svg1" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
 
 <defs>
 <mask id="msk1">
    <rect  fill="white" width="100%" height="100%" />   
     <rect id="r_top" fill="black" transform="rotate(60 12 12)"   x="0" y="-12"  width="24" height="12" >  
      
     <animate attributeName="y" dur="1s" begin="svg1.mouseover"  values="-12;0;-12" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1" restart="whenNotActive" /> 
   </rect>  
       <rect id="t_down" fill="black" transform="rotate(60 12 12)"  x="0" y="24"  width="24" height="12" >  
     
    <animate attributeName="y" dur="1s" begin="svg1.mouseover" values="24;10;24" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1" restart="whenNotActive" /> 
   </rect>  
  </mask> 
  </defs>
   
   <circle id="crc1" cx="12" cy="12" r="11" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke="white" />
<g mask="url(#msk1)" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke="white" >
  <path id="line1" d="M10 16 17 9V9M13 7" />
  <path id="arrow" d="m13 7h6v6" />
</g> 
 <path id="rec1" d="m17 14v5H6v-9h5" stroke-dashoffset="0" stroke-dasharray="30" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-linecap="butt" >
     <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" dur="0.65s" begin="svg1.mouseover" values="0;30;0" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive"/>
   </path>  
  
  
</svg>
</div>
```