# Каким образом сменить яркость изображения?

Tags: css3, svg, svg-animation, css-filters

**Суть:** и фильтр и маска на изображение, мне были отданы исходники т.е. наработки но хотелось управлять яркостью изображения, но не через `feColorMatrix` так как это не удобно.

Есть ли в SVG механизм попроще? Что бы было по типу как в CSS: `filter:brightness();`

Аналогичный вопрос на  [toster](https://toster.ru/q/602830)  от коллеги.

Приведу для примера, **что необходимо реализовать:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е это вот эти квадратные проёмы и как теперь менять яркость изображения с фильтром?

**Пример кода:**

```css
rect {
  fill: #ccc;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<svg width="500px" height="400px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
  <mask id="mask">

  <rect  x="20px"    y="20px"></rect>
  <rect  x="150px"   y="20px"></rect>
  <rect  x="280px"   y="20px"></rect>
  
  <rect  x="20px"    y="150px"></rect>
  <rect  x="150px"   y="150px"></rect>
  <rect  x="280px"   y="150px"></rect>
  
  <rect  x="20px"    y="280px"></rect>
  <rect  x="150px"   y="280px"></rect>
  <rect  x="280px"   y="280px"></rect>

  </mask> 
   <filter id="filter" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
   <feColorMatrix values="0.6927 0 0 -0.211588 0.15365 0 0.6927 0 -0.211588 0.15365 0 0 0.6927 -0.211588 0.15365 0 0 0 1 0"/>
  </filter>   
</defs>

<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3Q3J.jpg" 
       width="500px" 
       height="400px" 
       x="0" 
       y="0" 
       preserveAspectRatio="none"
       filter="url(#filter)" />
  
<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3Q3J.jpg" 
       width="500px" 
       height="400px" 
       x="0" 
       y="0" 
       preserveAspectRatio="none"
       mask="url(#mask)" />
</svg>
```

Comment: спасибо за правку

Comment: "он на toster.ru задал вопрос ему разумеется помогли один и тот же асс в JS:" на каком это языке)))

Comment: @HamSter  - не понял я

Comment: "помогли один и тот же асс в JS" набор слов

Comment: @HamSter  ааа....мой вопрос был отредактирован ...там был другой текст ...изначально этот вопрос задал мой Шеф Максим Ленский на тостер но доделать отдал мне - т.е найти способ легко менять цвет заливки ..т.е что бы без матрицы цветов менять в более тёмный цвет ...вопрос отредактировали и удалили эту часть но вот ту оставили ..и получился набор символов

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для информации можно почитать [Практические примеры применения масок svg](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/919186/28748)

```css
 .container {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  }
```

```html
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 640 480">
    <defs>
     <mask id="msk1"> 
   <rect fill="red" width="100%" height="100%" />
   <g fill="white">
      <rect  class="maskid" x='20px'  y='20px' width='100' height='90'></rect>
      <rect class="maskid" x='150px' y='20px' width='100' height='90'></rect>
      <rect class="maskid" x='280px' y='20px' width='100' height='90'></rect>

      <rect class="maskid" x='20px'  y='140px' width='100' height='90'></rect>
      <rect class="maskid" x='150px' y='140px' width='100' height='90'></rect>
      <rect class="maskid" x='280px' y='140px' width='100' height='90'></rect>

      <rect class="maskid" x='20px'  y='260px' width='100' height='90'></rect>
      <rect class="maskid" x='150px' y='260px' width='100' height='90'></rect>
      <rect class="maskid" x='280px' y='260px' width='100' height='90'></rect> 
  </mask>
    </g>
    </defs>

  <g>   
    <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqOMb.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" mask="url(#msk1)"/>
  </g>

</svg>
```

Затемнение фона регулируется насыщенностью цвета комбинированной маски, той части маски, которая отвечает за фон

`<mask id="msk1"> 
     <rect fill="#535353" width="100%" height="100%"  />`

```css
.container {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  }
</style>
```

```html
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 640 480">
    <defs>
     <mask id="msk1"> 
  <rect fill="#535353" width="100%" height="100%"  /> 
   <g fill="white">
      <rect  class="maskid" x='20px'  y='20px' width='100' height='90'></rect>
      <rect class="maskid" x='150px' y='20px' width='100' height='90'></rect>
      <rect class="maskid" x='280px' y='20px' width='100' height='90'></rect>

      <rect class="maskid" x='20px'  y='140px' width='100' height='90'></rect>
      <rect class="maskid" x='150px' y='140px' width='100' height='90'></rect>
      <rect class="maskid" x='280px' y='140px' width='100' height='90'></rect>

      <rect class="maskid" x='20px'  y='260px' width='100' height='90'></rect>
      <rect class="maskid" x='150px' y='260px' width='100' height='90'></rect>
      <rect class="maskid" x='280px' y='260px' width='100' height='90'></rect> 
  </mask>
    </g>
    </defs>

  <g>  
      <rect fill="black" width="100%" height="100%"  />  
    <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqOMb.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" mask="url(#msk1)"/>
  </g>

</svg>
```

Comment: Cаша ты видел ту фишку с toster ?

Comment: @ПавелВаршавский нет, но могу посмотреть, а надо? Кстати, твое решение не работает в FF

Comment: Не работает ? Да поглянь - ответ опять того же чувака

Answer (score 4):

Свой фан вариант приведу:

```css
*,
:before,
:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1529408632839-a54952c491e5?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80) center no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

h1 {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  overflow: hidden;
  color: transparent;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 150px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

h1 span {
  background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1529408632839-a54952c491e5?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80) center no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: right;
  padding-top: 10%;
  padding-right: 20%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1><span> ■ ■<br>■ ■</span></h1>
</div>
```

**P.S:** Только для современных браузеров, в FF работает, но в IE уже нет.

Comment: плюс поставил - в чате я сделал вообще проще что работать будет даже в IE6

Comment: @ПавелВаршавский, опубликуйте ответом свой рабочий вариант, а то где-то в каком-то чате )

Comment: Там просто блок с фоном и завален он inline-block с прозрачным тёмным фоном ...опытным путём вычислил нужные и сделал прозрачными - вот https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/mvXomY  а вот здесь я делал : https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70612/svg-chat

Comment: @HamSter а если понадобится не прямоугольниками вырезать, а более сложной формой? Тогда это решение не сработает. Поставил плюс, как за вариант решения.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, это же фан вариант, без претензий на ответ) Тут только для звездочек, снежинок, кружочков, треугольников ))) для всего набора html символов.

Answer (score 3):

Решил добавить rect и через `fill-opacity` менять яркость

Осталось решить проблему с дублированием изображения

```html
<svg width="640px" height="480px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <defs>
      <style>
        .maskid{
          fill:#fff;
          width:100px;
          height:100px;
        }
      </style>
      <mask id="mask">
      <rect class="maskid" x='20px'  y='20px'></rect>
      <rect class="maskid" x='150px' y='20px'></rect>
      <rect class="maskid" x='280px' y='20px'></rect>

      <rect class="maskid" x='20px'  y='140px'></rect>
      <rect class="maskid" x='150px' y='140px'></rect>
      <rect class="maskid" x='280px' y='140px'></rect>

      <rect class="maskid" x='20px'  y='260px'></rect>
      <rect class="maskid" x='150px' y='260px'></rect>
      <rect class="maskid" x='280px' y='260px'></rect>
  </mask>
    </defs>

  <g>   
  <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqOMb.jpg"
         x="0"
         y="0"
         width="640px"
         height="480px" />
  
  <rect width="640px"
        height="480px" 
        x="0" y="0"
        fill="#000"
        fill-opacity="0.8";" />
</g>
<g>
  <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqOMb.jpg"
         x="0"
         y="0"
         width="640px"
         height="480px"
        mask="url(#mask)"/>                                         </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: @Alexandr_TT  я имел ввиду на тостере видел ответ ?

Comment: @Alexandr_TT а почему мой пример не робит в FF ?

Comment: @Alexandr_TT  а можно как то сделать что бы было прозрачно чёрное а не светлое ?

Comment: то есть инвертировать цвета? то что прозрачно сейчас, сделать менее прозрачным, а фон наоборот сделать прозрачным?

Comment: что бы было как у меня

Comment: @Alexandr_TT Thank

Comment: @Alexandr_TT я уже голосовал раньше ...но почему то мой голос не учтённый был

Answer (score 3):

### Анимация трафарета

Увеличение ячеек

Трафарет в начальном положении находится в верхнем левом углу, затем происходит его увеличение до размера одной ячейки на весь экран.

```css
.container {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  }
```

```html
<svg id="svg1"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 640 480">
    <defs>
     <mask id="msk1"> 
  <rect fill="#535353" width="100%" height="100%"  /> 
 <g id="gr1" transform="scale(0.15)" fill="white">
      <rect class="maskid" x='20px'  y='20px' width='100' height='90'></rect>
      <rect class="maskid" x='150px' y='20px' width='100' height='90'></rect>
      <rect class="maskid" x='280px' y='20px' width='100' height='90'></rect>

      <rect class="maskid" x='20px'  y='140px' width='100' height='90'></rect>
      <rect class="maskid" x='150px' y='140px' width='100' height='90'></rect>
      <rect class="maskid" x='280px' y='140px' width='100' height='90'></rect>

      <rect class="maskid" x='20px'  y='260px' width='100' height='90'></rect>
      <rect class="maskid" x='150px' y='260px' width='100' height='90'></rect>
      <rect class="maskid" x='280px' y='260px' width='100' height='90'></rect> 
    </g>  
   <animateTransform
        xlink:href="#gr1"   
     attributeName="transform"
  type="scale"
  values="0.15;4.5;4.5;0.15;0.15"
  begin="1s"
  dur="10s"
  fill="freeze"
  begin="1s"
        restart="whenNotActive"
        repeatCount="indefinite"/> 
  
 </mask>
    </defs>

  <g>  
      <rect fill="black" width="100%" height="100%"  />  
    <image xlink:href='https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqOMb.jpg' width="100%" height="100%" mask="url(#msk1)"/>
  </g>
```

### Анимация скольжения трафарета

```css
.container {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  }
```

```html
<svg id="svg1"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 640 480">
    <defs>
     <mask id="msk1"> 
  <rect fill="#535353" width="100%" height="100%"  /> 
 <g id="gr1" transform="translate(0 0)" fill="white">
      <rect class="maskid" x='20px'  y='20px' width='100' height='90'></rect>
      <rect class="maskid" x='150px' y='20px' width='100' height='90'></rect>
      <rect class="maskid" x='280px' y='20px' width='100' height='90'></rect>

      <rect class="maskid" x='20px'  y='140px' width='100' height='90'></rect>
      <rect class="maskid" x='150px' y='140px' width='100' height='90'></rect>
      <rect class="maskid" x='280px' y='140px' width='100' height='90'></rect>

      <rect class="maskid" x='20px'  y='260px' width='100' height='90'></rect>
      <rect class="maskid" x='150px' y='260px' width='100' height='90'></rect>
      <rect class="maskid" x='280px' y='260px' width='100' height='90'></rect> 
    </g>  
   <animateTransform
        xlink:href="#gr1"   
     attributeName="transform"
  type="translate"
  values="0 0;100 120; 250 120;250 0;0 120;0 0"
  begin="1s"
  dur="4s"
  fill="freeze"
  begin="0.5s"
        restart="whenNotActive"
        repeatCount="indefinite"/> 
  
 </mask>
    </defs>

  <g>  
      <rect fill="black" width="100%" height="100%"  />  
    <image xlink:href='https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqOMb.jpg' width="100%" height="100%" mask="url(#msk1)"/>
  </g>

</svg>
```