# Выпуклая картинка

Tags: html, css3, svg, svg-animation, clip-path

[image]

Как реализовать такую форму обрезки изображения у тега `<img>` без использования `after/before`?

Answer (score 6):

Можно на css clip-path

Можно и на svg clip-path, снизу пример

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 149 75" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
   <defs>
      <clipPath id="clipPath">
       <path d="m2.5731133 296.75323c-4.59609-31.62533 1.44753-54.53056 10.76422-74.75323h128.54044c4.45956 1.01485 9.44931 1.355 8.56937 9.16466l0.55286 59.43142c-1.89632 3.33489-3.79485 6.66705-8.56936 6.38747z"/>
      </clipPath>
   </defs>
     <g transform="translate(-1,-222)">
      <image y="222" width="150" height="75"
             clip-path="url(#clipPath)"
             image-rendering="optimizeQuality" 
             preserveAspectRatio="none" 
             xlink:href="https://exklyziv.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/Tailande.jpg"/>
     </g>
  </svg>
```

Comment: Дальше обернуть svg в div и стилизовать уже это div

Answer (score 3):

### SVG Mask

Решения с помощью `mask` более богаты своими возможностями:

[Примеры применения масок svg](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/919186/28748)

**1. Вариант**

Маска работает в режиме `clip-path`.

```
<mask id="msk1">
<path fill="white" />
</mask>
```

То есть  зона  изображения, которую перекрывает `path` становится прозрачной

```html
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       width="1200" height="800" viewBox="0 0 1200 800" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"  >  
   <defs>
      <mask id="msk1">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black"/>
       <path fill="white" d="m 31.160638,11.39617 c 0,0 -17.690496,334.70985 -15.580319,502.16566 1.164647,92.42211 15.580319,276.85028 15.580319,276.85028 l 1112.195062,0 c 30.539,0 53.9779,-35.37784 53.9319,-61.12278 l -1.1985,-671.15221 c -0.047,-26.345457 -25.1895,-49.1946433 -51.5349,-49.1379254 z">
   </path>   
      </mask>
   </defs>
<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/9annC.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" mask="url(#msk1)" />


</svg>
```

**2. Добавляем полупрозрачный бордер к вырезанному изображению**

`<path fill="white" stroke="red" stroke-width="15"  .../>`

```html
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       width="1200" height="800" viewBox="0 0 1200 800" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"  >  
   <defs>
      <mask id="msk1">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black"/>
       <path fill="white" stroke="red" stroke-width="15" d="m 31.160638,11.39617 c 0,0 -17.690496,334.70985 -15.580319,502.16566 1.164647,92.42211 15.580319,276.85028 15.580319,276.85028 l 1112.195062,0 c 30.539,0 53.9779,-35.37784 53.9319,-61.12278 l -1.1985,-671.15221 c -0.047,-26.345457 -25.1895,-49.1946433 -51.5349,-49.1379254 z">
   </path>   
      </mask>
   </defs>
<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/9annC.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" mask="url(#msk1)" />


</svg>
```

### Варианты анимации маски

**1. Анимация формы вырезаемого изображения без бордюра**

Анимируется атрибут `d` `path`- задается начальное и конечное положение

Анимация начинается по клику на изображении:

```html
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       width="1200" height="800" viewBox="0 0 1200 800" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"  >  
   <defs>
      <mask id="msk1">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black"/>
       <path fill="white" d="m 31.160638,11.39617 c 0,0 -17.690496,334.70985 -15.580319,502.16566 1.164647,92.42211 15.580319,276.85028 15.580319,276.85028 l 1112.195062,0 c 30.539,0 53.9779,-35.37784 53.9319,-61.12278 l -1.1985,-671.15221 c -0.047,-26.345457 -25.1895,-49.1946433 -51.5349,-49.1379254 z">
     <animate attributeName="d" values="
    m 31.160638,11.39617 c 0,0 -17.690496,334.70985 -15.580319,502.16566 1.164647,92.42211 15.580319,276.85028 15.580319,276.85028 l 1112.195062,0 c 30.539,0 53.9779,-35.37784 53.9319,-61.12278 l -1.1985,-671.15221 c -0.047,-26.345457 -25.1895,-49.1946433 -51.5349,-49.1379254 z;
  
  m 31.160638,11.39617 c 0,0 77.863452,336.71337 68.313706,506.9596 -5.23657,93.35394 -68.313706,272.05634 -68.313706,272.05634 l 1112.195062,0 c 30.539,0 53.9779,-35.37784 53.9319,-61.12278 l -1.1985,-671.15221 c -0.047,-26.345457 -25.1895,-49.1946433 -51.5349,-49.1379254 z;

  m 31.160638,11.39617 c 0,0 -17.690496,334.70985 -15.580319,502.16566 1.164647,92.42211 15.580319,276.85028 15.580319,276.85028 l 1112.195062,0 c 30.539,0 53.9779,-35.37784 53.9319,-61.12278 l -1.1985,-671.15221 c -0.047,-26.345457 -25.1895,-49.1946433 -51.5349,-49.1379254 z"
   dur="4s"
   repeatCount="indefinite"
   begin="svg1.click" /> 
         </path>   
      </mask>
   </defs>
<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/9annC.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" mask="url(#msk1)" />


</svg>
```

2. К анимации добавляется полупрозрачный бордюр

   `<path fill="white"  stroke-width="10" stroke="#FF7E8F"`

```html
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       width="1200" height="800" viewBox="0 0 1200 800" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"  >  
   <defs>
      <mask id="msk1">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black" />
       <path fill="white"  stroke-width="10" stroke="#FF7E8F" d="m 31.160638,11.39617 c 0,0 -17.690496,334.70985 -15.580319,502.16566 1.164647,92.42211 15.580319,276.85028 15.580319,276.85028 l 1112.195062,0 c 30.539,0 53.9779,-35.37784 53.9319,-61.12278 l -1.1985,-671.15221 c -0.047,-26.345457 -25.1895,-49.1946433 -51.5349,-49.1379254 z">
     <animate attributeName="d" values="
    m 31.160638,11.39617 c 0,0 -17.690496,334.70985 -15.580319,502.16566 1.164647,92.42211 15.580319,276.85028 15.580319,276.85028 l 1112.195062,0 c 30.539,0 53.9779,-35.37784 53.9319,-61.12278 l -1.1985,-671.15221 c -0.047,-26.345457 -25.1895,-49.1946433 -51.5349,-49.1379254 z;
  
  m 31.160638,11.39617 c 0,0 77.863452,336.71337 68.313706,506.9596 -5.23657,93.35394 -68.313706,272.05634 -68.313706,272.05634 l 1112.195062,0 c 30.539,0 53.9779,-35.37784 53.9319,-61.12278 l -1.1985,-671.15221 c -0.047,-26.345457 -25.1895,-49.1946433 -51.5349,-49.1379254 z;

  m 31.160638,11.39617 c 0,0 -17.690496,334.70985 -15.580319,502.16566 1.164647,92.42211 15.580319,276.85028 15.580319,276.85028 l 1112.195062,0 c 30.539,0 53.9779,-35.37784 53.9319,-61.12278 l -1.1985,-671.15221 c -0.047,-26.345457 -25.1895,-49.1946433 -51.5349,-49.1379254 z"
   dur="4s"
   repeatCount="indefinite"
   begin="svg1.click" /> 
         </path>   
      </mask>
   </defs>
<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/9annC.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" mask="url(#msk1)" />


</svg>
```

3. К анимации изменения, вырезаемой формы изображения добавляется полупрозрачный фон

```
<mask id="msk1"> 
      <!-- Полупрозрачный фон-->
       <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="red"/>
       <path fill="white" .../>
</mask>
```

```html
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       width="1200" height="800" viewBox="0 0 1200 800" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"  >  
   <defs>
      <mask id="msk1">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="red"/>
       <path fill="white" d="m 31.160638,11.39617 c 0,0 -17.690496,334.70985 -15.580319,502.16566 1.164647,92.42211 15.580319,276.85028 15.580319,276.85028 l 1112.195062,0 c 30.539,0 53.9779,-35.37784 53.9319,-61.12278 l -1.1985,-671.15221 c -0.047,-26.345457 -25.1895,-49.1946433 -51.5349,-49.1379254 z">
     <animate attributeName="d" values="
    m 31.160638,11.39617 c 0,0 -17.690496,334.70985 -15.580319,502.16566 1.164647,92.42211 15.580319,276.85028 15.580319,276.85028 l 1112.195062,0 c 30.539,0 53.9779,-35.37784 53.9319,-61.12278 l -1.1985,-671.15221 c -0.047,-26.345457 -25.1895,-49.1946433 -51.5349,-49.1379254 z;
  
  m 1144.5542,8.9991946 c 0,0 4.1031,337.9695854 3.5955,506.9596054 -0.2749,91.49188 -3.5955,274.45331 -3.5955,274.45331 l -1.1985,0 c -0.823,10e-6 53.9779,-35.37784 53.9319,-61.12278 l -1.1985,-671.15221 c -0.047,-26.345457 -51.5349,-49.1379254 -51.5349,-49.1379254 z;

  m 31.160638,11.39617 c 0,0 -17.690496,334.70985 -15.580319,502.16566 1.164647,92.42211 15.580319,276.85028 15.580319,276.85028 l 1112.195062,0 c 30.539,0 53.9779,-35.37784 53.9319,-61.12278 l -1.1985,-671.15221 c -0.047,-26.345457 -25.1895,-49.1946433 -51.5349,-49.1379254 z"
   dur="8s"
   repeatCount="indefinite"
   begin="svg1.click" /> 
         </path>   
      </mask>
   </defs>
<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/9annC.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" mask="url(#msk1)" />


</svg>
```

Comment: @Js ученик Добавлен новый ответ. Посмотрите, если интересно