# Применение SVG mask в CSS правилах

Tags: javascript, css, svg

Топик с подобным же названием не подходит так как не вариант: [Практическое применение SVG mask](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/919186/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba-svg)

Интересует именно применение некой маски к обычному html тегу [img](http://htmlbook.ru/html/img) и так же не интересует анимация маски и прочее что не относится к телу вопроса

Я хочу применить маску SVG к неизвестному количеству изображений но выходит не понятка, изображений не видно, прилогаю код

```css
img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.grid {
  width: 480px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  margin: auto;
}

.grid-item img {
  mask: url(#mask);
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 155 219" width="155" height="219" style="display: none;">
  <defs>
    <mask id="mask"  maskUnits="objectBoundingBox" maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#000" />
      <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="60" fill="#fff" stroke="red" stroke-width="10"/>
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="#fff" stroke="red" stroke-width="10"/>
    </mask>
  </defs>
</svg>

<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1619732802548-bfa614fef77b?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=334&q=80" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1619782472846-eba4e6fb2275?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=334&q=80" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1619641046270-29a0b73d7a9f?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=334&q=80" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1619787942043-99ae128ca5c1?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=375&q=80" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1619785938189-264b15dc1694?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=334&q=80" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

**Что надо сделать что бы заработало mask из css ?**

Вот такого поведения я хочу добиться

```js
let svg = document.querySelectorAll(".grid svg");
let svgImage = document.querySelectorAll(".grid svg image");

svg.forEach(function(el) {
  el.setAttribute("viewBox", "0 0 155 219");
  el.setAttribute("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg");
});

svgImage.forEach(function(el) {
  el.setAttribute("x", 0);
  el.setAttribute("y", 0);
  el.setAttribute("width", "100%");
  el.setAttribute("height", "100%");
  el.setAttribute("preserveAspectRatio", "none");
  el.setAttribute("mask", "url(#mask)");
});
```

```css
.mask {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

.grid {
  width: 480px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 20px;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 155 219" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="155" height="219" class="mask">
  <defs>
    <mask id="mask">
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black"></rect>
      <circle cx="80" cy="120" r="60" fill="white" stroke="#c00" stroke-width="10" />
      <circle cx="50" cy="60" r="40" fill="white" stroke="#c00" stroke-width="10" />
    </mask>
  </defs>
</svg>

<div class="grid">

  <div class="grid-item">
    <svg>
      <image href="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1619783534896-ae45ba5c78d8?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=334&q=80" />
    </svg>
  </div>

  <div class="grid-item">
    <svg>
      <image href="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1619732514485-2f6896f9e34c?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=334&q=80" />
    </svg>
  </div>

  <div class="grid-item">
    <svg>
      <image href="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1619732802548-bfa614fef77b?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=334&q=80" />
    </svg>
  </div>

  <div class="grid-item">
    <svg>
      <image href="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1619782472846-eba4e6fb2275?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=334&q=80" />
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ассоциация https://stackoverflow.com/q/67447639/6339052

Comment: @Sevastopol' на самом деле у меня такой ответ ... в смысле такой же

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Маскирование — это одна из популярных операций (наряду с отсечением), используемая для скрытия частей элемента, которые под маской частично или полностью будут непрозрачны. Существуют различные способы сделать маскирование, как с помощью `CSS`, так и `SVG`. Однако, нужно понимать, что здесь имеются свои различия. Не всегда можно получить ожидаемый результат, как от использования бы `SVG`, применяя свойства `CSS`.*

Автор вопроса для маскирования использует `CSS` свойство `mask: url(#mask);`, значение которого ссылается на SVG-элемент. И получает следующий результат:

> Я хочу применить маску SVG к неизвестному количеству изображений но
> выходит не понятка, изображений не видно

И такой результат ожидаем, потому что `CSS` свойство `mask` работает не совсем так, как оно работало бы в `SVG`, в результате чего объект `<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#000" />` содержимого SVG-элемента полностью **перекрывает** изображение, поэтому мы его и не видим.

Для того, чтобы получить результат, близкий к ожидаемому, создадим внешний SVG файл со следующим содержимым:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?><svg role="img" viewBox="0 0 155 219" width="155" height="219" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<circle cx="90" cy="153" r="60" fill="#fff" stroke="red" stroke-width="10" stroke-opacity="0.5" />
<circle cx="45" cy="45" r="40" fill="#fff" stroke="red" stroke-width="10" stroke-opacity="0.5"/>
</svg>
```

и будем его использовать в качестве маски. Пример:

```css
img {
  width: 155px;
  height: 219px;
  mask: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e7/SVG_Mask_Circles.svg/155px-SVG_Mask_Circles.svg.png);
  -webkit-mask: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e7/SVG_Mask_Circles.svg/155px-SVG_Mask_Circles.svg.png);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1619732802548-bfa614fef77b?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=334&q=80" alt="">

<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1619787942043-99ae128ca5c1?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=375&q=80" alt="">

<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1619785938189-264b15dc1694?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=334&q=80" alt="">
```

Результат немного отличается от ожидаемого, потому что элементы содержимого SVG файла расположены на расстоянии друг от друга.

Если использовать такую маску, которую использует автор вопроса, то получим следующий результат:

```css
img {
  width: 155px;
  height: 219px;
  mask: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e8/SVG_Mask_100.svg);
  -webkit-mask: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e8/SVG_Mask_100.svg);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1619732802548-bfa614fef77b?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=334&q=80" alt="">

<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1619787942043-99ae128ca5c1?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=375&q=80" alt="">

<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1619785938189-264b15dc1694?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=334&q=80" alt="">
```

Как мы видим, и здесь результат немного отличается от ожидаемого, потому что элементы содержимого SVG файла накладываются друг на друга, тем самым перекрывая друг друга и изображение, в результате чего часть полупрозрачной границы маленького круга обрезается.

#### Вывод

В данном случае, чтобы получить такой результат, который нужен автору, а именно фигуру, состоящую из элементов с полупрозрачными границами, которые накладываются друг на друга и верхняя остается видимой, проще (*по времени*) использовать маскирование с помощью SVG. Однако, если правильно создать SVG файл, используя в качестве элементов не круги (`<circle>`), а произвольные фигуры, то совсем не сложно будет получить нужный результат.

---

**UPD/** Результат, который ожидает автор вопроса:

```css
img {
  width: 155px;
  height: 219px;
  mask: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0f/SVG_Mask_Redict.svg);
  -webkit-mask: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0f/SVG_Mask_Redict.svg);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1619732802548-bfa614fef77b?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=334&q=80" alt="">

<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1619787942043-99ae128ca5c1?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=375&q=80" alt="">

<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1619785938189-264b15dc1694?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=334&q=80" alt="">
```

Answer (score 4):

Я единственное что придумал, это подменить тег img на svg > image, идея была моя а вот с реализацией мне [помогли](https://qna.habr.com/q/983389), выглядит это так

```js
let images = document.querySelectorAll(".grid .item img");

images.forEach(function(it) {
  it.parentNode.innerHTML = `
<svg viewBox="0 0 155 219"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <defs>
    <mask id="mask">
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black"></rect>
      <circle cx="80" cy="120" r="60" fill="white" stroke="#c00" stroke-width="10" />
      <circle cx="50" cy="60" r="40" fill="white" stroke="#c00" stroke-width="10" />
    </mask>     
 </defs>
  <image href=" ${it.src} " width="100%" height="100%" x="0" y="0" 
  preserveAspectRatio="none" mask="url(#mask)"/>
</svg>
  `;
});
```

```css
.grid {
  max-width: 980px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  margin: 30px auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1619871172071-47964353b0d5?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=401&q=80" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1616425839183-c60d8f310fec?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=334&q=80" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1619059356114-b744d212faa2?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=334&q=80" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1611948018782-2a6e9c1d5ce6?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=333&q=80" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете применить SVG в качестве маски и легко настроить его размер и положение (как вы можете с фоновым изображением). Просто убедитесь, что вы установите правильное значение для viewbox:

```css
.img-container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  margin: 5px;
}

.clipped-img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  object-fit: cover;
  -webkit-mask: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 207 167"><path d="M199.6,18.9c-4.3-8.9-12.5-16.4-22.3-17.8c-11.9-1.7-23.1,5.4-32.2,13.2c-9.1,7.8-17.8,16.8-29.3,20.3c-20.5,6.2-41.7-7.4-63.1-7.5C38.7,27,24.8,33,15.2,43.3c-35.5,38.2-0.1,99.4,40.6,116.2c32.8,13.6,72.1,5.9,100.9-15c27.4-19.9,44.3-54.9,47.4-88.6c0.2-2.7,0.4-5.3,0.5-7.9C204.8,38,203.9,27.8,199.6,18.9z"></path></svg>') center/contain no-repeat;
  mask: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 207 167"><path d="M199.6,18.9c-4.3-8.9-12.5-16.4-22.3-17.8c-11.9-1.7-23.1,5.4-32.2,13.2c-9.1,7.8-17.8,16.8-29.3,20.3c-20.5,6.2-41.7-7.4-63.1-7.5C38.7,27,24.8,33,15.2,43.3c-35.5,38.2-0.1,99.4,40.6,116.2c32.8,13.6,72.1,5.9,100.9-15c27.4-19.9,44.3-54.9,47.4-88.6c0.2-2.7,0.4-5.3,0.5-7.9C204.8,38,203.9,27.8,199.6,18.9z"></path></svg>') center/contain no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container">
  <img class="clipped-img" src="https://picsum.photos/id/1074/800/800.jpg">
</div>

<div class="img-container" style="width:500px;">
  <img class="clipped-img" src="https://picsum.photos/id/1074/800/800.jpg">
</div>

<div class="img-container" style="width:150px;">
  <img class="clipped-img" src="https://picsum.photos/id/1074/800/800.jpg">
</div>
```

[Перевод ответа Temani Afif](http://stackoverflow.com/a/60492086/6339052)

Answer (score 2):

```css
img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  mask: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 450 450"><circle cx="170" cy="140" r="80" stroke="black" stroke-width="20"/> <circle cx="250" cy="280" r="150" stroke="black" stroke-width="20"/></svg>');
  -webkit-mask: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 450 450"><circle cx="170" cy="140" r="80"/> <circle cx="250" cy="280" r="150"/></svg>');
  --c: radial-gradient(farthest-side, #000 calc(100% - 20px), #0002 calc(100% - 8px) 99%, #0000);
  -webkit-mask: var(--c) 100% 100%/80% 80%, var(--c) 20% 20% /40% 40%;
  -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.item {
  width: 450px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

svg {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

circle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: red;
  stroke-width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2111143/pexels-photo-2111143.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-oratto-oficial-2111143.jpg&fm=jpg" alt="">
</div>
```